# How to add symbols from open source lib to Ghidra?

Tags: x86, decompilation, ghidra, symbols, debugging-symbols

I have a binary which I can tell is using rapidjson (open source C++ library) (header only/not dynamically linked). How can I load debug symbols from that? It would help to see the types, function names, class names, etc. from the code calling the library.

Other than by manually hunting down and changing signatures in the decompiled code. There must be an easier way.

(If there's a way to do this in IDA, I can switch to that instead, just for this.)

Comment: tried File->Parse C source ?

Comment: Well that worked extremely well @blabb